# Prove that, for $p$ of the form $±1+8k$, equations $x^2 − 2y^2 = −1$, $x^2 − 2y^2 = 1$ have infinitely many solutions in integers.

Tags: number-theory

Prove that, for $p$ of the form $±1+8k$, equations $x^2 − 2y^2 = −p$, $x^2 − 2y^2 = p$ have infinitely many solutions in integers.

Comment: How does $p$ relate to the equation $x^2 − 2y^2 = 1$ ?

Comment: I presume you mean $x^2-py^2=\pm1$?

Comment: What is the role of $p$ in the question?

Comment: are you asking: prove that for $x^2 − 2y^2 = −1,x^2 − 2y^2 = 1$ there is infinitely many solutions with the form $±1+8k$?

Comment: Probably the "2" should be replaced by "p", and the indicated congruences are necessary for there to be units with norm $-1$...

Comment: Possibly the question should be about $x^2-2y^2=\pm p$. After all $p\equiv\pm1\pmod 8$ implies that $p$ splits in $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$,  $h_K=1$, and we have infinitely many units of both norms $\pm1$? Junkquill, please check the question. It really doesn't make sense now.

Comment: My apologies, I've corrected the question now. It's supposed to be $x^2 − 2y^2 = −p$, $x^2 − 2y^2 = p$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen evidently so, from the edit a few seconds ago. Also, true, with completely elementary methods going back to Gauss, Lagrange and so on; just "reduction" of indefinite quadratic forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim follows from the properties of the ring of integers $R=\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt2]$ of the quadratic field $K=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$. Let's denote by $N$ the norm
$N(a+b\sqrt2)=a^2-2b^2$.

- $N(1+\sqrt2)=1^2-2\cdot1^2=-1$. Therefore there are infinitely many units of norms $\pm1$ in $R$, namely powers of $(1+\sqrt2)$.
- Because the class number of $K$ is $h=1$, $R$ is a PID.
- A prime $p>2$ splits in $K$ iff $2$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ iff $p\equiv\pm1\pmod8$.
- By the previous two bullets there exists elements of norm $\pm p$ in $R$ for any prime in these residue classes modulo $8$. Namely the generators of the prime ideals lying above $p$.
- By the first bullet there exists infinitely many such elements (the norm is multiplicative).

Comment: This is all textbook stuff. Switching to CW. Furthermore, if the OP is not familiar with basic algebraic number theory this will be all Greek to them.

Answer (score 1):

A trichotomy:

From page 164 of Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms, given prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 8,$ exactly one of the following three equations has integer solutions:
$$ 2 x^2 - p y^2 = 1, $$
$$ 2 x^2 - p y^2 = -1, $$
$$ 2 x^2 - p y^2 = -2. $$

This is in the chapter called The 2-Sylow subgroup.